# At what temperature can you use a "vulcanizing" tube repair kit?

Tags: innertube

I have a repair kit "REMA TT 02 Tour Patch Kit".  It says its glue/cement is "vulcanizing" but I don't know where to find a manual.  At what temperature can the glue work?  Ex: if the bike is outside and I am fixing it out there.

Comment: Maybe it is worth giving it a shot and contact the manufacturer with this question. It is not unlikely that they will answer. Then you could share the result with everyone. I think knowing the operational temperature range for the patches is important if you plan to have an unsupported tour in a remote location during the cold months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would see it the other way: manufacturers tend to write down critical "operating limits", if it's not clearly written in the package or in the instructions, it's likely that it's not critical (the reaction might be slower, but given the glue is not water-based, the "critical point" for temperature is unlikely to be the water freezing point). That remark is valid for established brand though, but Rema could be considered so.

For the manual, it's a simple leaflet with pictures.[image]

Comment: In other words, if there's an applicable temperature range, it should be stated on the instruction manual, correct? Anyway, for fun, I tried looking at the manufacturer safety data sheets to see if anything was stated. The MSDS only stated ignition temperatures, which are much higher than unprotected humans could survive, so that was a bust.

Comment: I would say if the applicable temperature range is narrower than the expected condition of use. Before replying, I searched at specs of competing products to see if something was written, but except a storage range of 5°C/30°C, I couldn't find anything. And on Rema's catalog, similar story: they wrote applicable temperature ranges for other products, but not this one. They just insist that the surface to vulcanize must be dry and clean.